# How to view the inserted rows when JPA testing with arquillian / hibernate?

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, jpa

I have an arquillian unit test that is writing a Note and passing the unit tests.

Now I would like to actually view what is being persisted into my SQLServer database.

When I open up SQLServer, I see my "Note" table, with all of the requisite columns...but there's no data.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="noteUnit"
        transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <jta-data-source>java:/jdbc/datasources/notes</jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />

            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2005Dialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class"
                value="org.hibernate.transaction.JBossTransactionManagerLookup" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I've tried various values for hbm22ddl.auto--'create-drop', 'update','validate', but since my test passes, I assume that the new rows are being inserted and then immediately removed by arquillian after the unit test?

Unit test below passes--meaning arquillian's xml file and all the other assorted plumbing appears to be set up correctly.  Is there a setting somewhere to save all the data that's being inserted?

```
    private NoteEntity createNote(){

        NoteEntity note = new NoteEntity();
        note.setGuid("123456789");
        note.setAuthorId("12345");

        return note;
    }

    @Test
    public void createNoteTest(){
        NoteEntity note1 = createNote();
        mEntityManager.persist(note1);
        Assert.assertNotNull(note1.getId());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally, jUnit are configured so that their transaction is in `defaultrollback=true` mode. This is done to avoid inserting test data in your database. You will probably find the configuration over your class definition or in an extended class.

Example for jUnit with Spring IOC configuration :

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath*:myPath/spring*Context.xml")
@TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback = true)
@Transactional
public abstract class AbstactSpringTestCase {
 ...
}
```